# url rewrite domain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

There's a lot of articles about htaccess that tell you how to redirect a domain name to another, but I can't find anything to do with rewriting the domain name.

My question is, how do I write my htaccess file so whenever the user goes to;

```
www.example.com/news/page
```

That user will actually go to;

```
www.example.com.10.01.12.xip.io/news/page
```

Below is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com.10.01.12.xip.io/$1 [R=permanent,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com.10.01.12.xip.io/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you properly You can use 301 redirect to go from one domain to another but can't rewrite domain name using .htaccess. Otherwise all people use other's domain in rewrite rule...